# How to bind a domain name to expressjs application

Tags: node.js, express

How to bind a domain name to expressjs application.My application is running on servername:1001
I want to bind it to www.domainname.com. How can I do this in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for the same answer.

I have just been using `app.use('/', router)` with a processor that then checks the domain off the req object.

```
router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {

  let path = req.path.replace(/^\//g,'').replace(/\/$/g,'');
  let domain = req.headers.host.split(':')[0];
  domain = domain.replace(/^www\./g,'');

});
```

This is the closest thing I've been able to come with to actually using express routes per domain. On my own, 4 years ago.

Now there seems to be this VHOST module: 
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/vhost.html

-Robert

Comment: Pointed this out as an issue on github and received this vhosts npm package as the answer: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/vhost.html

Answer (score -1):

Your DNS record you should use CNAME. As a value you should use the domain your hosting provider gave you ex. myapp.herokuapp.com(which on heroku side point to servername:1001).
If you are using hosting like heroku, you should setup to accept traffic for your application for that specific domain. That last configuration is being made on heroku management site.

Comment: CNAME records should only ever be pointed to another domain name.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Just saw my DNS configuration. CNAME does not point to port(which is in most cases dynamic), but in a specific domain. I'll edit my answer